# Как решить проблему нахождения касания объектов?

Tags: java, android, glsurfaceview

Программа должна быстро перемещать объект (шарик) и когда найдено касание объекта с другим шариком нужно первый шарик остановить. Я создаю класс SurfaceView. В параллельном потоке создаю цикл while в каждой итерации которого:

1. изменяю координату шарика
2. проверяю пересечение его с другим шариком.
3. если пересечение обнаружено, то останавливаю шарик.

И это всё хорошо работает пока скорость шарика небольшая (т.е. шарик перемещается за один цикл на 1-2 пикселя).

Скорость обновления экрана у меня на устройстве примерно 40-60 циклов в секунду. Ширина экрана 1280 пикселей. Я хочу, чтобы шарик пролетал весь экран примерно за 0.5 сек. Это значит, что за один цикл он должен перемещаться примерно на 40-60 пикселей. В результате если шарик находит пересечение и останавливается, то он останавливается не при касании другого шарика, а уже когда пересёкся с ним на 40-60 пикселей! Т.е. я не могу получить требуемый результат. Шарик не просто касается другого шарика, а пересекается с ним на 60 пикселей! Мне это не подходит.

Я читал, что при использовании OpenGL обновление экрана происходит быстрее (но насколько быстрее я не знаю) Если бы обновление экрана происходило НАМНОГО быстрее, то я смог бы перемещать объект за одну итерацию на 1-2 пикселя и перекрытие шариков было бы не заметно.
Подскажите, как мне решить проблему ПЕРЕКРЫТИЯ сталкивающихся шариков:

1. воспользоваться скоростью OpenGL, если это даст желаемый результат (во сколько раз OpenGL быстрее рисует экран?) или
2. всё же использовать класс SurfaceView, но каким-то образом исправлять ошибку НАЛОЖЕНИЯ объектов?

Comment: В любом случае плавность изображения ограничена частотой обновления экрана, и нет разницы между случаем, когда вы изменяете положение объекта один раз каждую новую отрисовку, и случаем, когда вы изменяете положение объекта более одного раза за отрисовку. Возможно, было бы проще в случае определения пересечения находить положение объектов в положении касания и рисовать уже это их положение...

Comment: @Вася Воронцов, в этом и состоит вопрос. Как найти точку касания, если я эту точку перескакиваю?

Comment: все равно должна быть максимальная скорость, типа скорости света, и если у вас за 1 кадр происходит скажем перемещение на 10 максимальных скоростей, то вам придется просчитывать сцену 10 раз прибавляя к шарам отрезки перемещения и проводя анализ столкновения.

Comment: @Вася Воронцов, у меня в вопросе указана примерная скорость 60пикс/сек. Я прибавляю это значение к координате за каждую итерацию в цикле. В результате, если объект столкновения размером меньше 60 пикселей, то шарик может пролететь сквозь него и не заметить столкновения. Он просто перепрыгнет его. А если ширина экрана в 2 раза больше (2560 px), то за один цикл придётся прыгать по 120 пикселей. Вероятность перепрыгиванию ещё больше возрастает